# How to disable Sitecore WFFM custom fields caching

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a custom field `SomeCustomFieldType` in **Sitecore WFFM** that shows on the left side of the Form Editor a property which is a dropdown with a list of choices.

```cs
[VisualProperty("Choose value", 99), 
    VisualCategory("Custom Properties"),
    VisualFieldType(typeof(CountryBasedListChoiceField))]
public string ChosenValue { get; set; }
```

Instead of using the out-of-the-box `ListChoiceField`, I wrote my own `CountryBasedListChoiceField`, which, based on some condition, figures out which choice items need to be displayed in the property dropdown:

```cs
public CountryBasedListChoiceField()
    : base(((object) HtmlTextWriterTag.Select).ToString())
{
    string formID = Sitecore.Context.Request.GetQueryString("formid");
    Language formLanguage = Language.Parse(Sitecore.Context.Request.GetQueryString("la"));
    Item formItem = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(formID, formLanguage);
    string countryName = SitecoreUtility.GetCurrentCountryISOCode(formItem, formLanguage);
    string choicesRootPath = CountryConfigurationManager.GetCountrySite(countryName).Metadata.FormsStylesheetsItemPath;
    Item choicesRootItem = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(choicesRootPath, formLanguage);
    ChoicesRoot = choicesRootItem.ID.ToString();
}
```

It really doesn't matter how the above code works, since it works just fine.

The problem I am having is that the code above is executed **only once**, the very first time that the user opens a form in the form editor and clicks on a field that is of type `SomeCustomFieldType`.

After that, the list of choices to be displayed must be cached because this code is never being hit anymore. Even closing the browser and reopening it is not enough to clear that cache -- iisreset obviously clears that cache.

I would like to know if there is a way to stop this caching from happening.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should check to ensure that it the rendering is not cached found here: `'/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Form'` (the version of WFFM I have open right now it is NOT the default). Also check to ensure that any renderings it is contained within are also not cached.

Looking at the forms code, the form item and field containers are constructed every time. I also checked the .ascx that is called and it has no default output cache. You can start by looking deeper in `Sitecore.Forms.Core.dll` at the class `'Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.SitecoreSimpleFormAscx'`, but I would try the simple first.

Comment: Caching happens globally for all `VisualProperties`, I think. It has nothing to do with a specific form. The constructor of `CountryBasedListChoiceField` is being called only once, the first time a form containing that type of field is being opened after application restart.